# Using pipe in if statement is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to shell scripting and stuck with this - I tried this if clause:

```
if [ unrar l "$filename" | grep -P "\.(?:r\d\d|r\d\d\d|.rar)$ ];
then...
```

It's not working, so tried this debug output - I get no output to `$grep_output`:

```
$grep_output = unrar l "$filename" | grep -P "\.(?:r\d\d|r\d\d\d|.rar)$"
```

If I execute this directly on the shell it's working without any problems:

```
unrar l "$filename" | grep -P "\.(?:r\d\d|r\d\d\d|.rar)$
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is your real code missing the trailing quotation mark?

Comment: Square brackets are used for comparison operators. You should drop them. In your debugging, the dollar in $grep_output causes the variable to be immediately expanded so you should drop that too.

Comment: "It's not working" isn't a great description of the problem you're facing.  In this case, it's fairly obvious what you've done wrong, but in general, it's a good idea to explain what you observe and what you expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the square brackets; these are not part of the syntax of the `if` statement, but an alternative way of invoking the `test` command, usually in order to use a binary operator:

```
if unrar l "$filename" | grep -P "\.(?:r\d\d|r\d\d\d|.rar)$";
  then...
fi
```

Comment: That is false, `if [ 1 ]; then echo "Foo"; fi` is a correct `Bash` syntax.